# Pandas – converting yes : no to True : False failing

Tags: python, pandas

My best efforts to convert a column with 'yes' 'no' values to True, False or 1 , 0 are failing. The column is 'subscribed'.

```
df.subscribed.unique() returns
array(['no', 'yes'], dtype=object)
```

Tried the following. None of them worked:

```
df.subscribed = df.subscribed.astype(int)
df.subscribed.map(dict(yes=1, no=0))
df.replace({'subscribed': {'yes': 1, 'no': 0}})
d = {'yes': True, 'no': False}
df['subscribed'].map(d)
```

Comment: sigh.... you need to assign back: `df['subscribed'] = df['subscribed'].map(d)` most pandas ops return a copy, some methods have `inplace` param which you need to set to `True` so the op is performed inplace

Comment: sigh ... thanks EdChum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As EdChum points out you need to assign back to the df.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'subscribed':np.random.choice(['yes','no'], 10)})
print(df)
```

Input:

```
  subscribed
0        yes
1        yes
2        yes
3         no
4         no
5        yes
6         no
7         no
8         no
9        yes

df =df.replace({'subscribed': {'yes': True, 'no': False}})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   subscribed
0        True
1        True
2        True
3       False
4       False
5        True
6       False
7       False
8       False
9        True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in a single line

df.col.map(dict(yes=1, no=0))

Comment: This should be `df.col.map({"yes":1,"no":0})`

Comment: The two are equivalent